# Why assigning a final field in a try-catch block within a static block is rejected?

Tags: java, static, initialization, final

I'm trying to write following class:

```
public class Secteur {
    private final static int num_secteur;
    static{
            try {
                num_secteur = SecteurDAO.getCurrNumSecteur();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

But I'm having following warning :

> The blank final field num_secteur may not have been initialized

The `SecteurDAO.getCurrNumSecteur()` method accesses the database in order to get the integer that will be set to num_secteur field.
What is the problem with my code ?

Comment: Because an exception could be thrown before assigning the value.

Comment: and what's the danger with this ?

Comment: The danger is that you might have an uninitialised variable, like the error message says. If you couldn't rely on it being initialised, you'd have to check if it's initialised whenever the class attempts to use it.

Comment: My personal preference is not to use static blocks for such a case, but instead to use a static method to return the value. The advantages are 1) you can name the method to make it obvious what it is for; 2) you aren't tempted to make the method do lots of things, E.g. initialize multiple variables; 3) you can invoke it whenever you want, E.g. in unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

The call to `SecteurDAO.getCurrNumSecteur()` might fail (throw an exception) and thus there's no value to assign to `num_secteur`. Hence it might not be initialized in case of an exception.

To fix that you might either want to initialize it with some special value (e.g. -1) or set that value in the catch-block.

Oh, and remove the `final` keyword, otherwise you'd get the error message "The final field num_secteur may already have been assigned". That's because you can only ever assign a value to a final field once and even if you know that assignment can't happen in case of an exception (because the exception will be thrown before) the compiler can't know that for sure and hence tells you that the variable *might* have been already assigned.

Comment: But I want to make sure my num_secteur field will never get assigned again

Comment: Then assign a value to temp_int in both the try/catch blocks, and then assign num_secteur = temp_int after the try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

As as been explained, if there is an exception, the variable might not be assigned at the end of the static initializer.

You might think of assigning to the variable before the `try` block, or after the `catch` block, but that can lead to 2 assignments to the variable, so that's disallowed.

You might think of assigning an invalid value to the variable in the `catch` block, but that still can lead to 2 assignments to the variable.

The best way to assign this variable exactly once, and still keep `num_secteur` `final`, is to use a temporary variable and assign it to `num_secteur` in a `finally` block.

```
private final static int num_secteur;
static
{
    int test = -1;  // Invalid value.
    try {
        test = SecteurDAO.getCurrNumSecteur();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Only assigned here, exactly once.
        num_secteur = test;
    }
}
```